# The TTY freezes after “Ctrl-A” hotkey and “s” pressing with GNU screen

Tags: 20.04, screen, gnu

I would like to split a window horizontally.
When I type `screen` and then press Ctrl-A and press s, the TTY freezes.
OS version: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Device: ASUS laptop

Comment: RTFM http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/focal/en/man1/screen.1.html .

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>s</kbd> in screen sends the underlying terminal a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>s</kbd> which causes it to stop.  You can resume with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>q</kbd>.

If you want split screen, you want <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>S</kbd> with a capital "S" not a lowercase "s".

Comment: No. TTY freezes, but terminal on GNOME does not. And how does TTY freeze: open another TTY and login, find the PID of that TTY and kill it, and check the process has been killed. But that TTY still freezes.

Comment: Yes, I know. ctrl-q should fix that, or follow directions as in the answer.   Or type ctrl-a ? and look at the help screen in screen.  You will find _S_ next to _split_ and _s_ next to _xoff_.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/xoff